# Divide 360 by inputed number, and increase by that number until == to inputed number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quick question, how would I do this?

This is what I have so far (not completed yet):

```
def cycleInN():
    dN = int(input("Angle values, how many values do you want to see?: "))
    n = dN
    newAng = 360/n
    for i in range(n):
        finalAng = newAng * n #Should I use i instead of n?
        print(list(finalAng))
```

I'm getting a 'float' object is not iterable

So basically, if I input `4`, `newAng == 90`. 
I want to increase newAng until it reaches 4, and at the end it should `== 360`.

Thanks.

Comment: `print(list(finalAng))` Why are you converting a float to a list?

Comment: increasing `newAng` does not equal four, `newAng` is greater than the input!!

Comment: @MorganThrapp I want to list it on one line. If I delete the list(), I get the results I want, but not in the order I need it.

Comment: That's now how you add things to a list. It's just trying to convert that variable to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
def cycleInN():
    dN = int(input("Angle values, how many values do you want to see?: "))
    n = dN
    newAng = 360/n
    for i in range(n+1):
        finalAng = newAng * i
        print(finalAng, end=', ')
```